# exclude-result-prefixes in XSLT is not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<comments xmlns="http://www.dsttechnologies.com/awd/rest/v1">
   <row xmlns="">
      <source>SYSTEM</source>
      <group>PRTL-TASK</group>
      <type>text/plain</type>
      <text mimetype="text/plain">Assigned to: DT73606</text>
      <date>2015-08-18</date>
      <posted>8 days ago</posted>
      <time>04:04:58-05:00</time>
      <userNameInfo href="awdServer/awd/services/v1/users/DT73606" userId="DT73606" id="1e1fd97d-2d14-4939-a009-5c94fdb7b754">
         <lastName xmlns="http://www.dsttechnologies.com/awd/rest/v1">All powerful UserId</lastName>
      </userNameInfo>
      <instanceId>2015-07-29-04.27.15.461040T01</instanceId>
      <link rel="self" type="application/vnd.dsttechnologies.awd+xml" href="awdServer/awd/services/v1/instances/2015-07-29-04.27.15.461040T01/history/comments/b5ee129a-0338-41c7-881b-ab8c1727de36" />
      <link rel="parent instance" type="application/vnd.dsttechnologies.awd+xml" href="awdServer/awd/services/v1/instances/2015-07-29-04.27.15.461040T01" />
   </row>
   <row xmlns="">
      <source>MANUAL</source>
      <group>PRTL-TASK</group>
      <type>text/plain</type>
      <text mimetype="text/plain">hai hello</text>
      <date>2015-07-29</date>
      <posted>3 weeks ago</posted>
      <time>09:04:25-05:00</time>
      <userNameInfo href="awdServer/awd/services/v1/users/DT73606" userId="DT73606" id="1e1fd97d-2d14-4939-a009-5c94fdb7b754">
         <lastName xmlns="http://www.dsttechnologies.com/awd/rest/v1">All powerful UserId</lastName>
      </userNameInfo>
      <instanceId>2015-07-29-04.27.15.461040T01</instanceId>
      <link rel="self" type="application/vnd.dsttechnologies.awd+xml" href="awdServer/awd/services/v1/instances/2015-07-29-04.27.15.461040T01/history/comments/6c09f55e-f06f-4fa1-abe4-4bc4eed14e6d" />
      <link rel="parent instance" type="application/vnd.dsttechnologies.awd+xml" href="awdServer/awd/services/v1/instances/2015-07-29-04.27.15.461040T01" />
   </row>
</comments>
```

I am trying to modify the above xml using XSLT in such a way that the output is as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<History>
   <comments>
      <row>
         <source>SYSTEM</source>
         <group>PRTL-TASK</group>
         <type>text/plain</type>
         <text mimetype="text/plain">Assigned to: DT73606</text>
         <date>2015-08-18</date>
         <posted>8 days ago</posted>
         <time>04:04:58-05:00</time>
         <userNameInfo href="awdServer/awd/services/v1/users/DT73606" userId="DT73606" id="1e1fd97d-2d14-4939-a009-5c94fdb7b754">
            <lastName>All powerful UserId</lastName>
         </userNameInfo>
         <instanceId>2015-07-29-04.27.15.461040T01</instanceId>
         <link rel="self" type="application/vnd.dsttechnologies.awd+xml" href="awdServer/awd/services/v1/instances/2015-07-29-04.27.15.461040T01/history/comments/b5ee129a-0338-41c7-881b-ab8c1727de36" />
         <link rel="parent instance" type="application/vnd.dsttechnologies.awd+xml" href="awdServer/awd/services/v1/instances/2015-07-29-04.27.15.461040T01" />
      </row>
      <row>
         <source>MANUAL</source>
         <group>PRTL-TASK</group>
         <type>text/plain</type>
         <text mimetype="text/plain">hai hello</text>
         <date>2015-07-29</date>
         <posted>3 weeks ago</posted>
         <time>09:04:25-05:00</time>
         <userNameInfo href="awdServer/awd/services/v1/users/DT73606" userId="DT73606" id="1e1fd97d-2d14-4939-a009-5c94fdb7b754">
            <lastName>All powerful UserId</lastName>
         </userNameInfo>
         <instanceId>2015-07-29-04.27.15.461040T01</instanceId>
         <link rel="self" type="application/vnd.dsttechnologies.awd+xml" href="awdServer/awd/services/v1/instances/2015-07-29-04.27.15.461040T01/history/comments/6c09f55e-f06f-4fa1-abe4-4bc4eed14e6d" />
         <link rel="parent instance" type="application/vnd.dsttechnologies.awd+xml" href="awdServer/awd/services/v1/instances/2015-07-29-04.27.15.461040T01" />
      </row>
   </comments>
</History>
```

The ultimate goal is to eliminate the namespaces. I am trying with the following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:v="http://www.dsttechnologies.com/awd/rest/v1" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="v">
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
   <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="v:comments">
      <History>
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="v:comment" />
         </xsl:copy>
      </History>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="v:comment">
      <row>
         <xsl:apply-templates mode="sans-namespace" />
      </row>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="*" mode="sans-namespace">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not getting the desired output despite using `exclude-result-prefixes="v"`.Could anybody please point out what's wrong here?

Comment: Why do you have `<xsl:template match="v:comment">`? I see no `<comment>` in the input.

Comment: Before you say that something doesn't work, read the spec. You are guessing incorrectly what exclude-result-prefixes is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you copy an element, you copy its namespace too. This has nothing to do with `exclude-result-prefixes`: namespaces that are in actual use will never be excluded.

In your example, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:v="http://www.dsttechnologies.com/awd/rest/v1"
exclude-result-prefixes="v">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes"  encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/v:comments">
    <History>
        <comments>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </comments>
    </History>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any alternative solution or workaround to get rid of the namespaces?

Comment: Yeah..I tried your suggestion. I am still getting the namespaces. Your answer helped me in optimizing the code.

Comment: @Ashok.N Is your result different from the one here: http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiKm ? Which processor are you using?

Comment: I apologize for not letting you know the fact that my input xml is changed. Actually the inut xml response is returned by the web service. Made some changes in that. Your answer holds true. I will delete my answer. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the template:

```
<xsl:template match="v:comments">
   <History>
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="v:comment" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </History>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="v:comments">
   <History>
      <comments>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </comments>
   </History>
</xsl:template>
```

should work in your case.

However, XSLT 2.0 provide the `copy-namespaces` and `inherit-namespaces` on the `<xsl:copy>` instruction but they don't seem to be working.

Comment: "*but they don't seem to be working*" They do work - on namespaces that are in scope for the copied node. They cannot "work" on the actual namespace that the node is in, because then the copied node would not be the same as the original.